# JPA one to many, fetch children with specific column value

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, filter, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have two entities in one to many relationship in my spring-data-jpa project.

Parent entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "code_group")
public class CodeGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String entityId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "codeGroupId", referencedColumnName = "entityId")
    private List<SystemCode> systemCodes;

    // .. getters setters
}
```

Child entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_code")
public class SystemCode implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String codeGroupId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ActiveOrInactive status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

`status` column is of **enum** type, it can only have `Active` or `Inactive` value.

My existing code works fine. It is fetching code group with associated system codes. I want to filter system code with `status='Active'`. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "codeGroupId", referencedColumnName = "entityId")
@Where(clause = "status= 'Active'")
private List<SystemCode> systemCodes;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create such methods in your repo:

```java
List<CodeGroup> getAllBySystemCodes_Status(ActiveOrInactive status);

default List<CodeGroup> getAllActive() {
     return getAllBySystemCodes_Status(ActiveOrInactive.Active);
}

default List<CodeGroup> getAllInactive() {
     return getAllBySystemCodes_Status(ActiveOrInactive.Inactive);
}
```